# FileUriExposedException while downloading file from OneDrive with ChooserIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-intent-chooser

I use a ChooserIntent to add files to my Application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType("*/*");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose file to import";
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Normally, e.g. when choosing a file such as a picture from internal or external storage, this returns a content:// Uri in onActivityResult(). This also works fine with DropBox and most other storage mediums, but when using OneDrive, it returns a file:// Uri leading to a FileUriExposedException in Android SDK 24+.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=42, result=-1, data=Intent 
   { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=file:///data/user/0/com.microsoft.skydrive/no_backup/stream_cache/myemail@email.com/5761/bewerbung.rtf typ=text/rtf flg=0x1000003 cmp=com.microsoft.skydrive/.intent.getcontent.ReceiveGetContentActivity }}
   to activity {com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.picker.PickActivity}:
   android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.microsoft.skydrive/no_backup/stream_cache/myemail@email.com/5761/bewerbung.rtf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

How can I either make OneDrive return files with a content:// Uri (preferably) or avoid the Exception from crashing my App?

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the latest OneDrive app? They should have addressed this ~9 months ago, when Android 7.0 shipped. You might be able to avoid the problem by setting your `targetSdkVersion` below 24, but that is a temporary solution.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version from June 21. I think I will send a message to Onedrive support and see what they recommend or if they can change anything about it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently Microsoft just wasn't aware of the problem and fixed it promptly after I sent a support ticket. Great support, but they should have fixed that problem with the launch of api 24.